# Email with attachment

Tags: android, email, android-intent

i am trying to send an email with an attachment using intent.
the file is a pdf stored in the raw folder.  it is less than 200k.
but it shows file too large to attach. Y?
 help me pls..

```
Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
in.setType("application/pdf");
in.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[]{email.getText().toString()});
in.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Android Development Course");
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://deepak.android.samples/raw/android");
in.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(in, "Sending email.."));
```

Comment: How are you trying to do it? Show us some code.

Comment: Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
   in.setType("text/html");
   in.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[]{email.getText().toString()});

Comment: in.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Android Development Course");    
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://deepak.android.samples/raw/android");
in.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri);startActivity(Intent.createChooser(in, "Sending email.."));

Comment: You can edit your original post and attach code to it. Click the "edit" button at the bottom of your question and attach your code.

Answer (score 4):

use this method

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, 
                     new String[]{"emailaddress"});
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Body");

String rawFolderPath = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() 
                       + "/" + R.raw.shortcuts;

// Here my file name is shortcuts.pdf which i have stored in /res/raw folder
Uri emailUri = Uri.parse(rawFolderPath );
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, emailUri);
emailIntent.setType("application/pdf");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
```