# How do I attach a .txt file to an email?

Tags: android, email

I am fairly new to android and I am having a problem with the email. I am trying to attach a text file to an email and send it, but when I do I get a "File too large" error. This is my first time setting up email within an application, can someone please help?

Code:

```
    File myFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/test.txt");
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(myFile);

    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);  

    String aEmailList[] = { "person@gmail.com" };    
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, aEmailList);     
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Test");  
    emailIntent.setType("plain/text");  
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is a test.");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

    startActivity(emailIntent);
```

Comment: Check out this post...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194673/email-with-attachment
... should be able to answer your question.

Comment: the code looks OK - how big is your file?

Comment: @ligi The file is not even 1kb

Comment: @RoshanSubudhi That link did not help, my app just crashed when I tried it.

Comment: I found the problem, the path I used to attach the file was different from when I created it.
Creation: new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "test");
Attach: new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/test.txt");

Answer (score 0):

> Hello , try this one.

```
public void sendMail(String[] mailTo,String[] cc,String subject, String body, String attachmentFilePath)
{
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);

    emailIntent.setType("plain/text");

    if(mailTo!=null)
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,mailTo);
    if(cc!=null)
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_CC, cc);
    if(subject!=null)
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    if(body!=null)
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(body));
    if(mailTo!=null)
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://"+attachmentFilePath));

    context.startActivity(emailIntent); 
}
```